# How to use regular expression in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I want to implement regular expression in realm database. Something like -

```
RealmQuery<User> query = realm.where(User.class);
query.regex("username", "ad?m");
result = query.findAll();
```

Is it possible to use regular expression in Realm.

Comment: Currently Realm doesn't support regular expression right now. Here is the github issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1377 to track this feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implemented in `Realm v2.3.0`.

```
RealmQuery<User> query = realm.where(User.class);
query.like("username", "ad?m");
result = query.findAll();
```